# Prediction errors for Adaboost

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, prediction, prediction-interval

I understand how the adaboost algorithm works to produce a prediction of a class, however one thing I haven't seen is how to get a measure of accuracy for that prediction.  For example, if I fit a logistic regression, then I get a set of coefficient estimates *and their standard errors*.  This allows me to create a prediction interval for a new unseen case, as well as a point estimate.  However, for adaboost, I've only ever seen formulae and algorithms for creating the prediction, but nothing for the prediction interval.  The only thing I can think of is the test set error - but this is a "global" error estimate.

Another, more mathematical way to formulate this question is: Suppose we fit an adaboost algorithm to data $D_{T}\equiv\{(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_T,y_T)\}$ and get an estimated prediction function $\hat{f}$.  Now we use this to predict $n$ new observations $(\hat{f}(x_{T+1}),\dots,\hat{f}(x_{T+n}))$ (we don't observe $y$ for these data points).  What is the mean square error matrix $MSE(\hat{y})=E((y-\hat{y})(y-\hat{y})^T)$?

Comment: How exactly do you fit the logistic regression to get standard errors? If I do maximum likelihood estimation, I will only get a point estimate with no standard errors. If I do Bayesian, I will get that; but I don't know if there is work on Bayesian Adaboost.

Comment: You can use the asymptotic properties of ML to get standard errors from the Hessian - this is a well known fact exploited by nearly every stats package that does logistic regression